# How to enter fullscreen mode on launch

Tags: macos, swiftui, fullscreen, xcode12

As the title is stating I would need some help to get my macOS app open in fullscreen mode when launching.

I'm using SwiftUI and Xcode 12.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested in the solution I managed to find a solution to my issue. Here is the code:

```
     WindowGroup {
         ContentView()
             .onAppear {
                 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                     if let window = NSApplication.shared.windows.last {
                         window.toggleFullScreen(nil)
                     }
                 }
             }
        }
```